# Google Map Current Location Arrow Head Pointer not showing

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am currently working on google maps. I already made the routing system. But I have a small problem, arrowhead like in google maps current location is not showing in my app. So please help anyone.

My App Sample Image not showing arrowhead pointer:

[image]

Google Map Sample Image:

[image]

Comment: Is your current location a custom marker which you added to the map?  Can you show the code behind the screen capture?

Comment: Nope, I dont use marker for that part. It's the default current location marker. I didnt add any code for marker too. Should I enable something else so that arrow head pointer appear?

Comment: I've worked a bit with Google Maps on Android before but I don't know what you are expecting to see.  Maybe include an image of your app but what you expect it to look like.

Comment: Here's google map current location current location. https://ibb.co/kpLWya
I would like to achieve it. And here's mine. https://ibb.co/iaTZJa

Comment: Thanks for making this clear, I understand now.  Well that arrow appears to be connected to GPS in some way, since it knows where North is.  Maybe you need to configure GPS in some way?

Comment: I tried to look for answers about gps, but I still dont get any answer. but still thanks for the response.

Comment: I think the arrow shows bearing. Did you try to move a bit with the device in your hand?

Comment: Yes, I do. No result :(